# MultipleMatchesException while using react webjar

Tags: reactjs, scala, playframework, webjars

I was using react with play-framework from webjar. While running the code `MultipleMatchesException` exception is thrown. After looking into the issue, I find `react.production.min.js` file in two locations. One in cjs and other in umd.

build.sbt line:   `"org.webjars" % "react" % "16.3.2"`

What is the difference between cjs and umd? Why are both being downloaded and how to specify only one to use???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

CJS = Common JS
UMD = Universal Module Definition

You need to be more specific in your webjars-locator usage, so something like:

```
@webJarsUtil.locate("umd/react.production.min.js").script()
```